# pthreads are not executing serially

Tags: c, synchronization, pthreads

I am new to these pthreads. I wrote a program so that instead of displaying the numbers randomly, it should display in order. I have used **pthrea_join()** method for that. The program is as follows:

```
int cnt=0,i=1;
pthread_t th[10];
int printmsg()
{
  cnt++;
  printf( "thread no. %d\n",cnt);
}
void tosync()
{
  if(i>0)
  pthread_join(th[i-1],NULL); // <---here i am blocking the previous thread..                         
  printmsg();
}
void main(void)
{
  pthread_create(&th[0], NULL,(void*)&tosync, NULL);
  for( i=1;i<10; i++){
    pthread_create(&th[i],NULL, (void*) &tosync, NULL);
  } 
  int y;
  for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
    pthread_join(th[i],NULL);
  return;
}
```

Still i am getting the numbers randomly...
plzz. help

Comment: It seems you have a problem when accessing the global variable `i`. From the main thread (increment) as well as from the worker threads. Other than that, what do you expect `th[0]` to do? Wait for itself?

Comment: sorry i forgot to edit that... even now i am getting the numbers randomly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pthread_join(th[i-1],NULL) this line have some problems. when you create a thread you increate the value of i. suppose 
create first three thread OS switch thrid thread start and OS switch to the main thread where it creates rest of threads. after create all threads the value of i is 10/
now suppose OS switch to thrid thread then he waits 10-1 = 9th thread to finish and similary go on.So ultimate it print always randomly. Your strategy is wrong.

try this

```
int cnt=0,i=1;
pthread_t th[10];
int printmsg()
{
cnt++;
printf( thread no. %d\n",cnt);
}
void tosync()
{

printmsg();
}
void main(void)
{
pthread_create(&th[0], NULL,(void*)&tosync, NULL);
for( i=1;i<10; i++){
pthread_create(&th[i],NULL, (void*) &tosync, NULL);
pthread_join(th[i],NULL); // <---here i am blocking the previous thread..   
} 

return;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should pass something into your `tosync` routine so that each thread knows which thread it should wait on. Also, the very first thread shouldn't wait on anyone. You can pass an argument in if you use the proper signature for the thread start routine.

```
void * tosync(void *arg)
{
  pthread_t *me = (pthread_t *)arg;
  if (me > th) pthread_join(me[-1],NULL);
  printmsg();
  return 0;
}
```

The `main` should return `int`. It's loop is now simplified, since the start routine no longer needs a cast. Since each thread is already joining with its predecessor, the `main` thread only needs to join with the last thread.

```
int main(void)
{
  for( i=0;i<10; i++){
    pthread_create(&th[i],NULL, tosync, &th[i]);
  }
  pthread_join(th[9],NULL);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the `toSync` function you are using the `i` value, the problem is that you don't know what value `i` has when the toSync function runs.

In an extreme case it could have the value 10 for all threads, it happens if the loop that creates the threads gets to run before any of the created threads can run.

The clean solution is to pass the `i` value as the parameter to `pthread_create` and let `toSync` use that instead of the global `i`. E.g.

```
int *id = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
*id = i;
pthread_create(&th[i],NULL, (void*) &tosync, id);
```

Other things to think about:

1. `toSync` needs special handling for thread with id 0 since it doesn't have any predecessor to wait for
2. The final loop in `main` shouldn't invoke `pthread_join` on threads 0-8 since they have already been joined. The result of calling `pthread_join` several times on the same thread is [undefined](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/pthread_join.3.html)

Comment: Using `malloc` for this is a major waste of memory and cpu time. Simply cast `i` to `void *` rather than taking its address, and cast it back to `int` in the thread start function.

Comment: Also note that it's wasted synchronization: calling `malloc` in one thread and `free` in another will always have some hidden synchronization cost obtain the memory and return it to a free pool for reusage.

Comment: True. If the id is only needed to keep track of the predecessor thread I vote for the solution @Joachim Isaksson provided - just pass on the address of the thread.

Comment: @R.. argh, don't teach things like that to starters. Here we have a case where somebody has difficulties to understand basic synchronization between threads and stuff like that and you tell him to violate the interface?

Comment: It's not a violation of the interface. `pthread_create` and the thread start function take *values* of type `void *`. The interface contract does not require this value to be a valid pointer to anything. The conversion between `void *` and `int` is implementation-defined, but every real-world implementation defines it in a meaningful way such that you can convert at least small intgers (and except on really exotic archs, *all* integers that fit in `int`) from `int` to `void *` and back without loss.

Answer (score 1):

What is happening is that your `tosync()` method uses the global variable `i` instead of knowing the value of `i` when the thread was actually started. If you want to pass `i` (or here the pointer to the previous pthread_t) to tosync so that it actually remembers which thread it should join with, you need to do pass it through pthread_create, something like;

```
void* tosync(void* ptr)
{
  pthread_t* threadIndex = (pthread_t*)ptr;
  if(threadIndex != NULL)
      pthread_join(*threadIndex, NULL); // <---here i am blocking the previous thread..                         
  printmsg();
}

...in the loop...

pthread_create(&th[i], NULL, tosync, &th[i-1]);
```

It's the last parameter to pthread_create that will be passed in as threadIndex in your method, if that contains the index, each thread will know its separate index.

Comment: Nice, you just have to be careful with the first thread, so the `pthread_create` call and the `tosync` must certainly contain some conditionals.

Comment: @JensGustedt Good point. It should be enough to check for NULL and have the first thread continue to pass NULL as a parameter. Fixed the code :)

Answer (score 1):

another approach:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

struct threadData{
    int id;
    pthread_t prev;
};


void tosync(void *data)
{
    struct threadData *td=data;
    if ((*td).prev!=0){
        printf("%i waiting\n",(*td).id);
        fflush(0);
        pthread_join((*td).prev,NULL); // <---here i am blocking the previous thread..                         
    }
    printf("%i runnning\n",(*td).id);
    fflush(0);
    free(td);
}

int main(void)
{
    int i;
    struct threadData *td;
    pthread_t nextThreadID=0;
    for( i=0;i<10; i++){
        td=malloc(sizeof(struct threadData));
        (*td).prev=nextThreadID;
        (*td).id=i;
        pthread_create(&nextThreadID,NULL, (void*) &tosync, (void *)td);
    } 
    pthread_join(nextThreadID,NULL);
    return 0;
}
```